# Unable to mount 3TB GPT HDD

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, gpt

I have a little Problem, my Home-Server didn´t mount my 3TB GPT.
Yesterday all was fine, this morning I realize that i cant go in my Network-Storage. First i thinked it was a network isue, but now i realize that my HDD isn´t mount on the Server.

The HDD is a half-year old 3TB WD NAS Drive with EXT4 Partition
After i connect via CLI to my Server i was unable to mount the HDD:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /media/test
mount: special device /dev/sda1 does not exist
```

So after this I checked, gdisk

```
gdisk -p /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 5860533168 sectors, 2.7 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 39C0E260-042B-49D4-8E6E-9BC50D737FD2
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 5860533134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2014 sectors (1007.0 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048      5860533134   2.7 TiB     8300
```

Seems that the partition is there.

But now dmesg give me a shock:

```
dmesg | grep sda
[  118.604171] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  118.604180] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  118.604193] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  118.604247] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  118.604262] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  118.604296] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
[  118.746661] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  118.746671] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  118.746684] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  118.746737] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  118.746752] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  118.746787] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
[  118.850077] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  118.850086] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  118.850099] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  118.850152] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  118.850167] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  118.850202] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
[  118.958434] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  118.958478] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  118.958493] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  118.958546] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  118.958561] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  118.958596] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 16
[  119.062741] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  119.062750] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.062763] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.062816] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.062831] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  119.062866] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 16
[  119.162205] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  119.162214] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.162228] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.162309] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.162325] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  119.162360] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 2
[  119.263608] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  119.263617] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.263630] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.263683] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.263699] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  119.263734] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
[  119.360690] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  119.360694] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.360701] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.360727] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.360735] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  119.360753] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
[  119.473960] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  119.473989] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.474003] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.474056] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.474072] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  119.474106] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 1
[  119.573920] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  119.573929] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.573943] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.573996] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.574011] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  119.681738] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  119.681746] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.681760] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.681832] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.681848] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  119.784225] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  119.784229] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.784235] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.784259] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.784266] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  119.897560] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  119.897569] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.897582] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.897670] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  119.897685] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  120.005416] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  120.005425] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.005438] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.005511] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.005529] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  120.106603] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  120.106612] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.106625] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.106678] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.106693] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  120.208834] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  120.208842] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.208856] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.208909] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.208924] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  120.307642] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  120.307650] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.307663] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.307716] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.307731] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  120.401843] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  120.401852] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.401865] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.401919] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.401934] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  120.520984] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  120.520993] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.521006] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.521081] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.521096] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  120.622166] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  120.622175] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.622188] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.622242] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.622257] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  120.772862] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  120.772872] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.772885] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.772938] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.772953] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  120.876604] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  120.876613] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.876627] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.876680] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.876695] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  120.976197] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  120.976206] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.976219] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.976272] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  120.976288] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  121.084561] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  121.084571] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  121.084584] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  121.084637] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  121.084652] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  121.188246] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  121.188255] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  121.188268] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  121.188321] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  121.188337] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  121.296177] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  121.296185] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  121.296198] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  121.296251] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  121.296267] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  121.404177] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  121.404186] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  121.404199] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  121.404274] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
[  121.404290] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  643.243134] EXT4-fs (sda): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[  643.243628] EXT4-fs (sda): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[  643.243997] EXT4-fs (sda): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[  750.164450] EXT4-fs (sda): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[  750.164863] EXT4-fs (sda): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[  750.165261] EXT4-fs (sda): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[  828.264361] EXT4-fs (sda): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 1366.861538] EXT4-fs (sda): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 1366.862017] EXT4-fs (sda): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 1366.862385] EXT4-fs (sda): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 1375.362443] EXT4-fs (sda): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 1909.793273] EXT4-fs (sda): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 1909.793652] EXT4-fs (sda): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 1909.793998] EXT4-fs (sda): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
```

Is there anything what i can do to restore the HDD, or some other Hints & Tips?

Thanks for the Help

Comment: Looks like a loose cable or a disk failure. Try the disk in another system.

Comment: You may try checking the disk with smartmontools.